# Rails 3: Create an "empty" ActiveRecord query object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible in Rails, to create an "empty" ActiveRecord Query object for a given model? Empty means for me a condition, that includes all possible rows in the db. I want to apply filters to that query afterwards.

At the moment I am using `Booking.where('id > ?', 0)`, but I believe there has to be a nicer way like `Booking.all()` - but `all()` returns an array and not an ActiveRecord. Here´s my code:

```
@bookings = Booking.where('id > ?', 0)
if !@day.nil?
    @bookings = @bookings.where('day = ?',@day)
end
if @project_id && !@project_id.empty?
    @bookings = @bookings.where('project_id = ?', @project_id)
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Booking.scoped should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scoped method discussed here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes

Also note that `@project_id.present?` is the same as
`@project_id && !@project_id.empty?`

Answer (score 0):

Use `unscoped` to create an empty query so you can build on it. (`scoped` is [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12756)).

```
@bookings = Booking.unscoped
if !@day.nil?
    @bookings = @bookings.where('day = ?',@day)
end
if @project_id && !@project_id.empty?
    @bookings = @bookings.where('project_id = ?', @project_id)
end
```

(BTW in the absence of this you could also initialise it with `Booking.where(true)` instead of the `id > 0` check; it's cleaner and likely to perform be better than doing a real condition check. But, unscoped is better still.)